# Displaying a form with fields stored within a ArrayList<Object> using JSF and Primefaces

Tags: forms, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I've struggling with this issue from a few days now.

I need to display a form. The fields of the form are **generated dynamically**, they are **stored within an ArrayList** (by Object I mean an instance of the class Attribute, a very simple class with two String fields: label and value). In other words, I have no direct get and set methods to access them.

This is not a problem when the involved fields are "flat" fields, such as text fields, textareas, etc. The whole thing gets painful when it comes to diplaying data as selectboxes, or other dynamic fields (since the value of my fields is not updated).

I didn't find anything on the www about this, each example I found uses backingBean fields as value of the components, and it all works like a charm.

I've been coding for a while now, using JSF and primefaces, I've tried to add some JSTL, but I can't seem to get over the problem. I do not think that posting code is necessary at this time (I'm avaiable to give further information about it though), I would simply like to know if anyone had the same problem, or if I am looking at the problem from a wrong point of view.
Is there a widely accepted approach to this kind of scenario?

**Update (code):**

Here is my (simplified) xhtml page (please notice that the object"card" in my backingBean (newBacking) is just a container of attributes:

```
<h:form id="COSMO-FORM-NEWCARD">     
    <p:dataTable var="curAttribute"
                 value="#{newBacking.card.attributes}"
                 rowIndexVar="curAttributeIndex">

        <f:facet name="header">New card: #{newBacking.card.classname}</f:facet>

        <p:column width="25%">
             <f:facet name="header">Attribute Name</f:facet>
             <h:outputText value="#{curAttribute.label}" />                    
        </p:column>

       <p:column>
           <f:facet name="header">Attribute Value</f:facet>

               <p:selectOneMenu id="#{curAttributeIndex}" value="#{curAttribute.value}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{newBacking.lookupActivated()}" var="curItem" itemLabel="#{curItem.label}" itemValue="#{curItem.value}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>

       </p:column>
    </p:dataTable> 
    <br />
    <p:commandButton value="Create" action="#{newBacking.commitAction()}"/>
</h:form>
```

And here is my CosmoAttribute class:

```
public class CosmoAttribute {

    private String label;
    private String value;
    // Other fields + getters and setters
}
```

Can some one explain why I am getting "Empty id attribute is not allowed" when I try to render the form? My p:selectOneMenu can't even see my curAttribute variable.

I cannot even bind my dyncamic field to a backing UIComponent, since I should create a Collection of UIComponents, and I cannot perform the binding with an element of a colletcion.

I'd like to keep the advantages of JSF, but since I've been struggling for many days, I'm ready to pursue different approaches.

Comment: I, for one, think that some code would help. Specifically, `Attribute` class, and page code (I suppose you are displaying fields in a loop). And, a bit more explanation of the problem (what's not working, are there any exceptions...).

Comment: In which way the fields are getting generated dynamically ? generating components dynamically like selectOneMenu in PrimeFaces can be a pain, this should be done on the server-side where you generate the component by code! furthermore if the generated components are HTML standards like a normal select input, this could be done easily on the client-side (JS) but here you would lose the JSF tier (validators, converters etc..). I don't like the dynamic approach in JSF and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Added some code. The attributes are generated by a backend servlet, and I'm accessing them as an ArrayList<Object> stored within a container class (Card). I cannot control that part of the system.

Comment: Can your `p:selectOneMenu` see `curAttribute` variable in a simple datatable, like in your post? Since that is a simplified page code, it could be an issue with other components you use.

Comment: As a quick look the ID can't be a number... I'm not sure why it's empty!